# An appropriate alternative to chi2 for paired, categorical data (tables larger than 2X2)

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am analysing a data set consisting mostly of categorical data. This has resulted in a number of contingency tables (mostly, but not always larger than 2X2) that need statistical testing. Now, I would love to use Chi squared tests on these tables and carry out some appropriate post-hoc analyses to see what is going on exactly, but there is a problem.

That is, all rows (not the columns) contain an x amount of data points from the same subjects, and thereby violate the test's assumptions. This is inherent to the data type. The three "types" in the table below refer to different types of referential expressions, which are all naturally produced at least once (but usually much more often) by every subject. These are the frequencies and this is what the data look like:

```r
data <- matrix(c(408, 377, 235, 141, 228, 148), ncol=3)
colnames(data) <- c('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
rownames(data) <- c('language1', 'language2')
as.table(data)  
             type1      type2      type3
language1    408        235        228
language2    377        141        148
```

Now, what I want to know is whether there is a connection/dependency relationship between the "language" variable and the "type" variable. I have done a lot of reading, checking forums, and asking around, but I simply have no clue how to solve this. Can anyone name an appropriate test for this type of data? (I have looked into McNemar, Fisher's, Cochran's Q-test etc. but have sadly not experienced an epiphany so far. And of course I do need to have the results analysed soon ...). I would be very grateful for any type of advice that gets me closer to a solution!

Comment: You're asking about paired data which is usually a deliberate study design feature. But in your problem description you mention you sort of "incidentally" have some repeated measures. It sounds like they are not balanced, and further it sounds like you don't have the subject identifier to identify which respondents have provided multiple entries and what they are. Is that correct?